# Is any Borel measurable function in the function space $\mathscr{L}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the relation
$$\tag{3}
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{u}\tilde{v}\ d \lambda\right| \leq\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\tilde{u}|^{2}d \lambda\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\tilde{v}|^{2} d \lambda\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
where $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{v}$ are Borel measurable functions and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
I was considering if it could be shown using Hölder's theorem:
$$\tag{2}
\left|\int u v\ d \mu\right| \leqslant \int|u v|d \mu \leqslant\|u\|_{p} \cdot\|v\|_{q},
$$
where $u\in\mathscr{L}^p$, $v\in\mathscr{L}^q$,  $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, and with the definition $\|u\|_{p}:=\left(\int|u(x)|^{p} \mu(d x)\right)^{1 / p}$. If all Borel measurable functions belongs to $\mathscr{L}^2(\lambda)$ then eq. $(2)$ gives us the relation in eq. $(1)$. Can someone tell me if that is actually the case?

Comment: You could get a case $0 \leq 0 \cdot \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the functions vanishes almost everywhere both sides of the inequality are zero, and you're done. Suppose neither vanishes almost everywhere. If one of the functions is not in $L^2$
then the right side of the inequality is infinite and you're done. If both functions are in $L^2$ you're done.

You're done.

(No, of course it's not true that every Borel function lies in $L^2$. Let $f(x)=x$.)

Comment: I am new to measure theory, and still have not learned about "almost everywhere", but the last part of your answer makes sense. Thank you. :)